# How is AWS KMS more secure than traditional method of storing keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, encryption, amazon-s3, cryptography

So I read this

```
Traditionally, keys have been managed in haphazard ways, from SCP-ing 
keys around your instances to baking them into machine images. The safe 
way to manage high-value keys has been to employ dedicated Hardware 
Security Modules (HSMs), either on-premise or with the AWS CloudHSM 
service. In either case, HSMs are expensive and hard to use.
```

I believe KMS is the same concept of using an HSM. From what I understand instead of hiding/securing the key you are using the KSM "vault" and sending your data to it to get encrypted and the decryptor does the same.

So doesn't it all boil down to this: instead of securing the keys, now we have to secure access to our KSM store? I don't understand how that is better. Someone else can get access to my KMS as easily as they get access to my key is that not so?

I am just trying to understand the benefit of this system (and hsm) in it's simplest form (disregarding envelope encryption for now

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **HSMs** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. Depending on the question you may be able to get help on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/about), or [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access to a HSM is timebound. If you lose your keys, anybody that has them can encrypt/decrypt data, produce signatures or perform any other cryptography as long as they want. Of course you can revoke a certificate, but that does not affect a key in many cases (for example it is still good for decryption after certificate revocation).

If you use a HSM, when you discover access compromise, you can disable the attacker's access to the HSM very quickly, and no further data is compromised. Of course the attacker can fully use your keys as long as they have access to the HSM, but not afterwards.

Also securing and equally importantly, auditing access to a HSM is much easier than to a key stored somewhere else. As a key never leaves a HSM, you don't have to care about auditing things like copied key usage (practically impossible) - you have information on exactly who accessed what key, for what purpose. You can grant and revoke such access at will.

A HSM usually provides other aspects of key management as well, for example key distribution may become much easier.

So yes, of course you still need to guard access to the HSM and contained keys. But for the reasons above, it still makes key management much more secure if used properly.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Can I ask why envelope encryption is better or is that another topic?

Comment: I think that's a different topic, but in very short, two main reasons: symmetric encryption is much less resource-intensive (ie. much faster) than asymmetric, and also enveloping lets you change the outer asymmetric key without having to reencrypt the whole bulk of data.

Comment: And both questions are off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I thought about this before answering, and I accept you are right - it may technically be off-topic. But I do think that this question is very much related to programming. It's not a direct source code question per se, but I thought these kind of programming decisions (where to store keys) are really important in the end from the software aspect, so it's worth to answer this type of question and spread security knowledge so that people produce more secure code. But again, I didn't want to argue - just my point of view.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I asked about KMS not HSM. In other words, a "tool used primarily for programming" implementing HSM.