# AWS Key Management Service - What if an attacker gets access?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, security, encryption

Let's say, I'm using AWS Key Management Service to manage encryption keys and secure my web service database. For each user in the database I'm using a Data Key to encrypt his information and then store the Encrypted Data Key with the encrypted data.

To decrypt data, I pass the Encrypted Data Key in a Decrypt API request. AWS KMS uses my Master Key (CMK) to decrypt the Data Key and then it returns the plaintext Data Key. I use the plaintext Data Key to decrypt the data.

What if an attacker gets access to the web server and runs a Decrypt API request for each Encrypted Data Key?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is AWS KMS more secure than traditional method of storing keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259062/how-is-aws-kms-more-secure-than-traditional-method-of-storing-keys)